# Writing One to One function in predicate logic.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic

I'm a little confused on how to write a One to One function in symbolic form.

Initially, I was thinking it would be: $∀x,y∈Z, x \ne y → f(x) \ne f(y)$, but my gut is telling me this is wrong. Any hints/tips?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a function $f:Z\to Z'$ to be One to One means that there are no two different elements of $Z$ that get mapped to the same element of $Z'$. This formalizes to
$$\forall x,y\in Z:x\neq y\Rightarrow f(x)\neq f(y)$$
Usually, the contrapositive, equivalent statement
$$\forall x,y\in Z: f(x)=f(y)\Rightarrow x=y$$
is used.